# doPostBack from C# with JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dopostback

hi I have one parent page which opens a pop up window, and user makes some changes on child pop up page then clicks a save button.
When the user clicks the save button, I want to doPostBack to the parent page so that the changes made in the pop up window can be seen in parent window.

*Question* : How can I achive the above scenario?

I want to write the script code in aspx.cs file, I tried

```
string script = "";
script = "<script>window.opener.__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '')</script>";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Literal1, typeof(Literal), "yenile", script, true);
```

but this did not do anything, no errors just nothing.

I am new to JavaScript, need help with all steps.

Comment: You don't need the script tags, there's a boolean parameter to include them when you call ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ChildWindowResult" />
        </div>
        <hr />
        <input type="button" value="Open Dialog" onclick="window.open('MyDialog.aspx', 'Dialog');" />
        <asp:Button ID="HiddenButtonForChildPostback"  runat="server"
            OnClick="OnChildPostbackOccured" style="display: none;" />
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="PopupWindowResult"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The MyDialog page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postData() {
        var resultField = $("input[type='hidden'][id$='PopupWindowResult']", window.opener.document);
        var parentPosDataButton = $("[id$='HiddenButtonForChildPostback']", window.opener.document);

        resultField.val($("#<%= SomeValueHiddenField.ClientID  %>").val());
        parentPosDataButton.click();
    }
</script>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="SomeValueHiddenField" />
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="PostData" Text="Click Me" />

protected void PostData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SomeValueHiddenField.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PostData", "postData();", true);
}
```

But I believe that it would be much better to utilize here some pop-up controls like PopUpExtender from the AjaxControlToolkit library or dialog from the jQuery-UI.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use `ClientID`:

```
string script = "";
script = "<script>window.opener.__doPostBack('" + UpdatePanel1.ClientID + "', '')</script>";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Literal1, typeof(Literal), "yenile", script, true);
```

Comment: Well ... to be honest, I didn't read the whole question, I just saw your `__doPostBack` and in ASP.NET it mangles the ID for runat="server" controls, so you always have use the full ClientID in `__doPostBack`.

Comment: Why don't you just do `UpdatePanel1.update();` from the code-behind in the pop-up?

Comment: Scott I think you are missing something, I am trying to do postback to Parent page's updatepanel in the child page(pop up page).In addition, I will try that thanks.

Comment: You need to use UniqueID, not ClientID, for the control id in __do PostBack.

Comment: @Ray thanks Mr.Ray, I must admit I am a noob when it comes to JavaScript.

Comment: @Ray - Thanks.  I wasn't thinking; it's a habit to use ClientID with JavaScript.  ClientID uses underscores to concatenate the control's id with its containers for use client-side while UniqueID uses dollar signs to concatenate the control's id with its containers for use server-side.

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter is to whether include script tag or not

So, if you do

```
RegisterClientScriptBlock(page,type, "<script>foo();</script>", true);
```

You will end up with:

```
"<script><script>foo();</script></script>"
```

So, change your last parameter to false, or better yet, remove the tags in the string

Answer (score 0):

Review the following suggested solution:

http://livshitz.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/use-popup-to-postbackupdate-its-parentopener-without-losing-viewstate-values-and-close/#more-16