# OnClick and OnClientClick

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dopostback, onclientclick

I have an image button on a pop up page which is opened by another page

```
<asp:ImageButton 
        ID="Button_kalem_islemikaydet" 
        runat="server" 
        CausesValidation="False" 
        ImageUrl="~/images/butonlar/buyuk/Kaydet.jpg"  
        meta:resourcekey="Button_kalem_islemikaydetResource1" 
        OnClick="Button_ust_islemikaydet_Click" 
        OnClientClick="f2()"  
        Width="100" />
```

`f2()` is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function f2() {
            opener.document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "hello world";
            opener.document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = "hello world";

            window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;            
        } 
</script>
```

And `Button_ust_islemikaydet_Click` is another method implemented in aspx.cs file and it updates the database tables which are shown in the parent page in a GridView.

What I am trying to do is to doPostBack I mean refresh the opener(parent) page.And with these above codes refresh is working.However, parent page still shows the same data before the refresh.And the reason is that **`OnClientClick` works before `OnClick` method**
So my question is that is there any way I can run  the method on `OnClick` and finish it and then run the `OnClientClick` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form id="aspnetForm" runat="server">
    <asp:Button Text="Click Me" ID="ClickMeButton" OnClick="ClickMeButton_OnClick" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="UpdateOpenerHiddenField" Value="false" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //1st approach
        var updateOpenerField = window.document.getElementById("<%= UpdateOpenerHiddenField.ClientID  %>");
        if (updateOpenerField.value === "true") {
            f2();
            updateOpenerField.value = "false";
        }

        // for the 2nd approach just do nothing
        function f2() {
            alert("Hello, opener!");
        }
</script>
</form>


protected void ClickMeButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //1st approach
        UpdateOpenerHiddenField.Value = "true";

        // 2nd approach
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshOpener", "f2();", true);
    }
```

Comment: I tried the second approach Onestein but it did not work I will try the first one now, thank you.

Comment: As I suppose, the button that cause postback placed in an UpdatePanel. If so then you still can use the 2nd approach but register startup script with the ScriptManager class instead of the Page.ClientScript: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "RefreshOpener", "f2();", true);

Comment: thanks Onestein, it worked.As you seem good at these things I want to ask another question, I asked this like two days ago [Refresh GridView(only) in parent window with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154423/dopostback-from-c-with-javascript).If you have any idea I am expecting it on that question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't run server side code (OnClick event handler) before client side. OnCLientClick event was added to perform some validation before post back. There is only one way to do it - update the f2 method and post data on server via ajax

Comment: Ajax is not so complicated. use jQuery framework, it has a lot of good samples

Comment: I'll try that but before do you think if I can use that `f2()` in aspx.cs with like `RegisterClientScriptBlock`?

Comment: Yes, you can. But browser will reload page two times, first - when post data to server, second - when script will refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

You can put your javascript inside a PlaceHolder tag which you make visible in your server-side OnClick handler.

aspx code:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="refreshScript" visible="false" runat="server">
  window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
  window.close();
</asp:PlaceHolder
```

cs code:

```
protected void button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // do whatever
  refreshScript.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: how is that going to help Ray?I am confused.

Comment: When the page first loads, the placeholder is not visible, so the script is not rendered to the page, so it doesn't do anything. After the click, you make the placeholder visible, the script is rendered to the page, so it executes and reloads the opener. I suppose It should also close the popup, so I added that to my answer