# passing a parameter to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(Session["sayfaTuru"]);            
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshOpener", "f2(" + i + ")", true);
```

---

```
function f2(i) {
            if (i == 1) {//CariKartHareketleri
                opener.document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = "hello world";
                window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href; //çağıran sayfayı yeniliyor

            }
            else if (i == 2) {//islemler
                opener.document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = "hello world";
                window.opener.__doPostBack('GridRefreshPanel.ClientID', '');

            }
            else if (i == 3) {//hizmet listesi
                opener.document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = "hello world";
                window.opener.__doPostBack('GridRefreshPanel.ClientID', '');

            }

        }
```

it says `i` is undefined when I debug the code in `f2(i)`.What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I learned many things from this problem,  but I still do not have an answer.I tried every idea given in the answers but `i` is still `undefined`...

**EDIT:** I still have no solution for undefined reasons :), but the answer I accepted would normally be my solution.

Comment: Can you link the code for `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`?

Comment: @Exelian http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479390.aspx#javawasp2_topic5

Comment: Do a view source on the emitted script blockin the browser. What do the function calls look like?

Comment: I call the function like on the first lines of my question Mr.Wiseman, and having no problem with the browser as much as i understand. @James Wiseman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried debugging the server-side code to see if

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(Session["sayfaTuru"]);
```

is giving you what you want in the first place?

---

Well seeing as how the above has been checked, I went ahead and created my own test, and it worked just fine.  Here's the test I used:

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function f2(i, hiddenFieldId, updatePanelId) {

        console.log(i + ', "' + hiddenFieldId + '", "' + updatePanelId + '"');
        var hiddenField = window.opener.document.getElementById(hiddenFieldId);

        switch (i) {

            case 1: //CariKartHareketleri
                hiddenField.value = "hello world 1";
                window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href; //çağıran sayfayı yeniliyor
                break;

            case 2: //islemler
                hiddenField.value = "hello world 2";
                window.opener.__doPostBack('' + updatePanelId + '', '');
                break;

            case 3: //hizmet listesi
                hiddenField.value = "hello world 3";
                window.opener.__doPostBack('' + updatePanelId + '', '');
                break;

            default:
                alert("error");
                break;      

        }
    }
</script>
```

**C#:**

```
Session["sayfaTuru"] = 2; // initialize for testing purposes

int i = Convert.ToInt32(Session["sayfaTuru"]);

string script = string.Format("f2({0}, '{1}', '{2}');", 
                              i.ToString(), 
                              this.HiddenField1.ClientID, 
                              this.GridRefreshPanel.UniqueID);

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshOpener", script, true);
```

**console.log Output:**

```
2, "HiddenField1", "GridRefreshPanel"
```

Comment: tank you Mr.Scott I will try it.Thanks for all the help.

Comment: this is realy an educational code for me Mr.Scott, however I am still getting `i` is undefined.I guess something else is not right.

Comment: I don't know what to say. Maybe try posting your entire HTML markup and entire C# code-behind so we can see what could be causing this.

Comment: they are really long codes, I don't wanna mess up stackoverflow :D, thanks for all your help. I used `window.opener.name.indexof()` to get it working not that I am happy about it but it works.I will declare your answer as the answer of the question if I can't get any other answer in three days.Thank you so much Mr.Scott.

Comment: Ok ... Just for grins though, what if you didn't create an `i` variable at all and simply passed in the value directly? In my example above, remove the `int i = ...;` line and then change `i.ToString(),` to `(Session["sayfaTuru"]).ToString(),`.  Let's see what that does.  I'm wondering if we are having scope issues with the `i` variable.

Comment: I had tried that Mr.Scott and and tried it now.i is undefined again.

Comment: What if you change the name of your `i` variable in your JavaScript to `index` just for grins? Also, where exactly you are placing all this JavaScript?  And, what does your `ScriptManager` HTML markup look like? Reason I ask is that in my example, I use this:  `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"  AsyncPostBackTimeout="300" EnablePartialRendering="true" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true" ScriptMode="Debug" />`

Comment: I only have this `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptLocalization="False">
                    </asp:ScriptManager>` about ScriptManeger on my aspx  and I am placing the js code after `<title></title>`.I'll check those ScriptManager attributes Mr.Scott.And I tried index and it is undefiend again.

Comment: You definitely need `EnablePartialRendering="true"` if you are using `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: I didn't write the whole code and I am supposed to leave like it was for some reasons, I am also noob ^^ now I added those properties, and tried still no change, but it was good to learn something more thank you :)

Comment: Ok ... well, all I can say is that I'd need to look at your actual source code to see what is wrong.  It sure seems like it's something else, as I know it works for me since I tested it.

Comment: I will inform you if something new happens Mr.Scott, thanks for all your effort on helping.

Comment: No problem. Hope you figure it out!

Answer (score 2):

[`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479390.aspx#javawasp2_topic6) takes a script *definition*, not an *invocation*.

Since you want to define the function externally, use [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479390.aspx#javawasp2_topic8) instead:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "RefreshOpener", "MyJavaScriptFile.js", true);
```

---

To execute the JavaScript function `f2` with parameter `Session["sayfaTuru"]` on button click, use the following (not tested):

1. In `Page_Load`, add the JavaScript file which contains the definition for `f2`:

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(...);
       // Do other stuff
   }
   ```
2. Then add the actual button click listener which will invoke `f2`:

   ```
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="f2(<%=Session['sayfaTuru']%>);" />
   ```

Comment: Not true.  It doesn't take a function at all - takes a string that is anything script-related.

Comment: I am sorry I am a noob when it comes to JavaScript, how am I suposed to pass my parameter to a function in an external js file?

Comment: @Burn just wanted to make sure - are the calls to `RegisterClientScriptBlock` (etc.) inside of `Page_Load`?

Comment: No they are not, they are in a button_clicked method.I read this "This class would be best used when you have a JavaScript function that you want to initiate when the page is loaded" when you sent the link but check the answer of this question [OnClick must work and finish before OnClientClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175695/onclick-must-work-and-finish-before-onclientclick).

Comment: When do you want the function `f2` to be executed - on page load, or on button click?

Comment: sweet thank you, Matt I will try it as soon as I go to my office tomorrow morning.Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I tried it Matt, I also set the build action as Embedded Resource from Properties cos I was getting "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'RefreshAfterSaveClick' is undefined".Then I added this `<script type="text/javascript" src="../RefreshAfterSaveClick.js"></script>` and it worked but `i` is still `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be getting an Exception thrown in your code-behind.  You're trying to concatenate strings, but i is an integer.  Try this instead:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(Session["sayfaTuru"]);            
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshOpener", "f2(" + i.ToString() + ")", true);
```

Though I would actually prefer to use String.Format:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(Session["sayfaTuru"]);            
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshOpener", String.Format("f2({0})", i), true);
```

Comment: I already tried the first one Kon, I will try the one with String.Format.

Comment: Have you tried to debug and step through the code-behind to see what the value of i is?

Comment: Second one did not work, too.Well in the aspx.cs file in this line `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshOpener", "f2(" + i.ToString() + ")", true);` `i` is 1 or 2 or 3 as I wanted.However, in the aspx file where I wrote `f2(i)` it say undefined.

Comment: View source of your web page that gets rendered and search for the invocation of f2().  See what is being passed into it.

Comment: thank you I will try it and inform you Kon.thanks for your help.

Comment: hi, it says "`i` is undefined" Kon, so i guess nothing is passed.

Comment: Yep, sounds like something is jacked up on the server-side.

Comment: still no solution, I had to use `window.opener.name.indexof("blabla.aspx")`.It is working but not making me happy.Thanks for your interest Kon.